# Regex doesn't capture group well

Tags: javascript, regex

I currently have a regex

```
/^Newsletter pour (.+)?<?((([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,}))>?$/i
```

I want it to match `Newsletter pour ome <ome@yahoo.com>` and `Newsletter pour ome@yahoo.com`.

Now i did something like this regex.exec('Newsletter pour ome@ya.co') and want to detect whether the email is at position 1 or 2 of the array. But the problem is that sometimes the first letter of the email gets put in index 1 and the remaining part gets put in index 2.

Please help. How do i rectify this

Comment: `(.+)?` is not the same as `(.+?)`. You can replace `(.+)?` with `(.*?)`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LRKkDY/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your regex is too long,that can do it simple.try `/^Newsletter pour (?:\s*(\w+(?: \w+)*) )?<?((\S+)@(([^.]+)\.[^>]+))>?\s*$/i`,except the first one,the reset are the same 2:email,3:username,4:host,5:whois.

```
describe('matching address', () => {
    const regex = /^Newsletter pour (?:\s*(\w+(?: \w+)*) )?<?((\S+)@(([^.]+)\.[^>]+))>?\s*$/i;


    test('address without header', () => {
        let result = "Newsletter pour ome@yahoo.com".match(regex);

        expect(result[1]).toBeUndefined();
        expect(result[2]).toEqual('ome@yahoo.com');
        expect(result[3]).toEqual('ome');
        expect(result[4]).toEqual('yahoo.com');
        expect(result[5]).toEqual('yahoo');
    });

    test('email without sharps', () => {
        let result = "Newsletter pour ome ome@yahoo.com".match(regex);
        expect(result[1]).toEqual('ome');
        expect(result[2]).toEqual('ome@yahoo.com');
    });

    test('email enclosed with sharps', () => {
        let result = "Newsletter pour ome <ome@yahoo.com>".match(regex);

        expect(result[1]).toEqual('ome');
        expect(result[2]).toEqual('ome@yahoo.com');
    });

    test('header includes whitespaces', () => {
        let result = "Newsletter pour ome sanni john ome@yahoo.com".match(regex);

        expect(result[1]).toEqual('ome sanni john');
        expect(result[2]).toEqual('ome@yahoo.com');
    });

    test('header includes whitespaces & email eclosed with sharps', () => {
        let result = "Newsletter pour ome sanni john <ome@yahoo.com>".match(regex);

        expect(result[1]).toEqual('ome sanni john');
        expect(result[2]).toEqual('ome@yahoo.com');
    });
});
```

Comment: your solution is good but it doesn't validate that the email is a valid email. it allows ome@yahoo. or ome@yahoo.c which isnt a valid email

Comment: validate & extract data should be by two steps.they tare two things.so you first validate using regular email regex,and than extract data by this regex.

Comment: by my suggestion,your code will be run fast and more cleary,the time of the complex regex will matching data more than the simple one,because regex matching need precompile regex into a tree.

Comment: please can u help me with the current version. I just updated my question. the first format is Newsletter pour ome <ome@yahoo.com>

Comment: what if i wanted to match Newsletter pour ome sanni <ome@yahoo.com>

Comment: I‘m sorry,I'm too late to answer your problem,because I was out of power there last night,I have updated my answer.